# Regarding Haskell type classes (Num vs Read)

Tags: haskell

Can someone please explain what I am missing here:

```
Prelude> :t read
read :: (Read a) => String -> a 
Prelude> read "4"

<interactive>:1:0:
    Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraint:
      `Read a' arising from a use of `read' at <interactive>:1:0-7
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

`read "4"` raises an error as ghci doesn't know which concrete type we want, it only knows that we have a `Read` type class. `read "4" :: Int` works fine. This is clear to me.

Now, following the above logic, I expected `fromIntegral 4` to raise an error:

```
Prelude> :t fromIntegral
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
Prelude> fromIntegral 4
4
```

However, it works fine. Why is a type annotaion NOT required in this case? I expected the above to fail; and ONLY

```
Prelude> fromIntegral 4 :: Int
```

to work.

NB - I am reading "Learn you a Haskell for great good" and have covered till chapter 5. Is what I am asking discussed in chapter 7 (or some other chapter)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works because of [type defaulting](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4), which causes ambiguous type variables to be defaulted to `Integer` or `Double` (or some other user-defined default). This only happens for `Num` and its subclasses.

In GHCi, [the rules for defaulting are relaxed](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) to also work for `Show`, `Eq` and `Ord`, and also `()` is added to the list of default types. This allows expressions like `[] == []` to type check.

Answer (score 4):

Difference is that read could potentially result in any type, whereas fromIntegral yields a number. 
There is some defaulting going on with regard to numbers in ghci, so that ghci can just use the default type.